# Port forwarding not working when client is on same local network?

Tags: port-forwarding, home-networking, isp

**EDIT:** Based on the answers below, the question was in error. The issue was not due to port forwarding, but rather **trying to access a server on the local network via our public IP** in the first place. It appears you can only do this with a router that supports [NAT loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback) (or "hairpinning"), which is a sufficiently obscure feature that it's often hard to find out for sure whether you have it or not.

[This MikroTik wiki article](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Hairpin_NAT) helped me understand the issue (though I can't attest to its accuracy...)

---

I have a personal website which is hosted off of a server I keep in my shoe closet. I have configured my domain name to point to my home network's public IP address, and have set up port forwarding on the router so that requests get forward to the server.

Everything works as expected **except when I'm on my home Wi-Fi**. That is, when I'm at a friend's place or connected to my mobile hotspot, I can visit https://<my-domain>.com in a browser, and it works fine. I can `ssh <my-domain>.com` and that also works fine. I can even `ssh <my-public-ip-address>` and that works, too.

But when I'm on my home Wi-Fi, none of it works at all. The web page just keeps on trying to load until it times out (no DNS errors). Same with ssh. I suppose the biggest mystery is that `ssh <my-public-ip-address>` doesn't work (while naturally, `ssh <my-server's-LAN-ip-address>` works fine), which leads me to believe that the router isn't doing port forwarding for requests that come over the local network.

Any tips for how I can better diagnose the problem? I've been on and off the phone with my ISP (Spectrum) like a dozen times, but they haven't given me a definitive answer. Is there any way to determine which device my timed-out requests are getting sent to when I try ssh-ing to my public IP address? Or any solutions outright?

Comment: Search this site for "NAT hairpin".

Comment: TIL. Okay, this sounds to me like the most viable explanation—I used to be on a router that supported NAT hairpinning, and based on [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/HomeNetworking/comments/czbhxj/accessing_public_address_locally/), it seems like my current router does not. Mystery solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this points you in the right direction.
When you are on you home network you don't need port forwarding.
Depending on the firewall you use.   You can do redirect that just redirects the traffic to the server or just have a internal DNS that gives out the internal LAN IP of the server.  I have never gotten the redirection to work correctly.

Some firewalls will allow the redirection to an IP when an internal LAN IP is trying to reach an internal IP.  Some consider this a security risk and don't allow it.  Most if not all don't allow routing in a loop. Example out the wan and back in the wan.

If possible also in the router or if you are running a DNS server you can just put in a record for that host and your problem is solved.
For Debugging:
nslookup can be of help nslookup .com <private IP address would give you the local IP.  and nslookup .com  would give you another.

What you are asking the ISP is beyond what they do.
Edit:  Sorry I see in my firewall it is called NAT Reflection.

Comment: Thank you so much. This resolved my problem, even if it did not clarify my understanding—I already had pi-hole set up on my server, so I added the appropriate DNS records to it and now everything works fine. However, what I still don't understand is why `ssh <my-public-ip>` worked on my previous router (AmpliFi Instant) and not on my current one (Sagemcom Fast 5280, provided by Spectrum).

Comment: I would just say,  It is just the difference in routers sonic wall will not let you do this by default but you can go through the pain full task of setting it up.   For PFsense you can just click a box and it will do it.